# How to make two existing interfaces become equal?

Tags: typescript

I already have two interface `A` and `B` and there instances `a` and `b`.

```
interface A {
    FA(): void;
}

interface B {
    FB(): void;
}

declare const a: A;
declare const b: B;
```

How can I make these two interface become equal so they can share each others properties?

```
a.FA();
a.FB();
b.FA();
b.FB();
```

I have tried:

```
interface A extends B {}
interface B extends A {}
```

but failed with

> Type 'A' recursively references itself as a base type.ts(2310)

I don't want a new `type C = A & B`, because converting my existing instance `a` and `b` into type `C` every time is annoying.

Interface `A` already exists in 3rd party library with method `FA(): void`

I want to call some custom extended methods like `FB(): void` when I get an instance `a`.

And such methods are all put into my custom interface `B`.
`B` also has a class definition:

```
class B extends MyBase {
    FB() {
        this.FA();
    }
}
```

The runtime part is done by modifying prototype, and type checking is the left problem.

Comment: Could you explain what is the actual goal behind this?

Comment: It looks like X/Y problem for me. Very unsulual case

Comment: I don't understand why you need `B` at all instead of just using declaration merging on `A`.  Could you provide a [mcve] that shows what you mean by "modifying prototype" for an interface?  Is `A` actually an imported class?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a third interface as common interface like this:

```
interface common{
  FA(): void;
  FB(): void;
}

interface A extends common{
}

interface B extends common {

}

declare const a: A;
declare const b: B;

a.FA();
a.FB();
b.FA();
b.FB();
```

[PlaygroundLink](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&ssl=19&ssc=8&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgQewLYbSA3gKGWQDEBBACgEoAuZANzWABMBuQkgIStoebYF98%20UJFiIUpZBAAekEEwDOqTNjz5Bw8NHhJkHKbIjyl6LDmQF1QphAQAbOFBToQCsMji1SbG-cfOcN2QAI1oONnw4ADoyKjZo4i5KNmCYimT8VMS4oA)

Comment: A is in 3rd party library and not modifiable in my case.

Comment: @WangGengxin you said : `I have tried: interface A extends B {}` !! that is because I recommend you this solution

Comment: Sorry I haven't make it clear enough. But `interface A extends B {}` can be done through declaration merging.

Answer (score 0):

### **What about extends them on the go like so?**

```
interface A {
    FA(): void;
}

interface B {
    FB(): void;
}

interface A extends B {}

declare const a: A & B
declare const b: B & A

a.FA();
a.FB();
b.FA();
b.FB();
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm%20QMVQAoBKALmQDcB7YAEwG4sBfLLUSWRFAIUxzz4epCjXpNW7cNHhI0yCAA9IIOgGdkfDJLoQEAGzhQUCaiDVhkcCugBkmrLoNGTZi8gBGFPvdRs4AHSEpEyBQiFYHkHEJExR4bFAA)

Comment: Instance `a` of type `A` is everywhere, and convert all of them into `A & B` would be a lot of work for me.